# Number theory questio

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[image: here is captured question]

I have studied for about 250 questions and there are many questions i can't take.. i considered but i don't know how to start... how can i solve this?
In second question, there even hint..

[image: i want toknow]
Well im so glad if you tell me how to solve

Comment: For the second one, note that $gcd(a,b)=1$ implies that there exist $x,y$ integers such that $xa+yb=1$, implying $xam+ybm=m$.  So, since $d\mid am$ and $d\mid bm$, you know that...

Comment: It is better not to put two unrelated questions together. Ask them as separate questions.

Comment: For the first one you can prove that ever number is a multiple of 9999...999